# Sending notification using PHP to IOS devices

Tags: php, ios, xcode

i have an app that receives push notification which build on Xcode using Objective-c. I did follow this tutorial [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) by Ray Wenderlich, the notification work fine and I can receive immediate message. I have my own web site and I want to use it to send the notification using PHP. I did try to find a tutorial about that but I could not.

Is it possible to use my web site to send the notification?
CAN I use PHP file to send the notification?
Do I need to change the SSl Certificate to a Production SSL?

Her is the PHP code which I use at the moment:

```
<?php

$deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Hello app';



$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
{   
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}
else
{   
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

}

// Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);

?>
```

I hope my question is clear, and hope some one to give me some information or to direct me to a tutorial that could help me.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use the same page on your website. You need to create another certificate for production with which you will be deploying your APP to store. Also you need to change the URL from `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` to `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

Comment: That is easy, but do I need to delete the development SSl r it does not matter.

Comment: You don't need to delete the development certificate. You can still use it for your development build app.

Comment: I have this message after I run the PHP from my web site: Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out

Comment: Do you think because the app is not already on Apple Store so I have that error

Comment: [Good tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) It is important that the push certificate type matches the gateway you are using. Development push cert goes to sandbox, ad hoc or distribution cert goes to not-sandbox

Comment: This may help https://ihackthati.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/setting-up-push-notification-in-an-ios-chat-application/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can certainly send push notifications to iOS devices using PHP. But before sending any notification, you will be needing:

1) Apple Push Certificate (APNs Certificate) - This can be generated from Apple Developer Center. Note that the certificate is per app and there are two kind of certificates, Development and Distribution. Follow [This Link](http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates) on how to generate one.

2) Device Token for you device - This is to be done on your iOS app. You code on iOS App might look something like this.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    self.storedDeviceToken = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    self.storedDeviceToken = [self.storedDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", self.storedDeviceToken);
}
```

Now that you have all the tools required for push notification, you can start with your PHP script.

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$gateway = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'YourPassphrase!!';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Yoooo! What\'s up man!';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'PathToGeneratedCertificateOnStep1');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    $gateway, $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

For more details on the payloads supported by Apple Push Notification [visit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html).

**NOTES:**

- > If you are installing the iOS app manually for testing then the device
  >   token is only valid for sandbox notification. So, your `$gateway` will
  >   be `'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'`
- > Notification cannot be received on simulator.